# how do i run this cpp file in ros

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

i am new to ROS currently working on ROS Kinetic,i have an issue when i run this linefollowing.cpp file using the command "rosrun roscv linefollowing.cpp" (where roscv is the package name & "linefollowing.cpp" is the .cpp file),

the error;

```
/home/badhrisrini/line_follow_ws/src/roscv/src/linefollow.cpp: line 19: using: command not found
/home/badhrisrini/line_follow_ws/src/roscv/src/linefollow.cpp: line 20: using: command not found
/home/badhrisrini/line_follow_ws/src/roscv/src/linefollow.cpp: line 21: namespace: command not found
/home/badhrisrini/line_follow_ws/src/roscv/src/linefollow.cpp: line 22: static: command not found
/home/badhrisrini/line_follow_ws/src/roscv/src/linefollow.cpp: line 24: float: command not found
/home/badhrisrini/line_follow_ws/src/roscv/src/linefollow.cpp: line 25: float: command not found
/home/badhrisrini/line_follow_ws/src/roscv/src/linefollow.cpp: line 26: float: command not found
/home/badhrisrini/line_follow_ws/src/roscv/src/linefollow.cpp: line 28: class: command not found
/home/badhrisrini/line_follow_ws/src/roscv/src/linefollow.cpp: line 36: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/badhrisrini/line_follow_ws/src/roscv/src/linefollow.cpp: line 36: `  image_transport::Publisher image_pub_; //image publisher(we subscribe to ardrone image_raw)'
```

the code in this file is;

```
    #include <ros/ros.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>     //make sure to include the relevant headerfiles
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <cv_bridge/CvBridge.h>
#include <cvaux.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include "turtlesim/Velocity.h"
     
/*here is a simple program which demonstrates the use of ros and opencv to do image manipulations on video streams given out as image topics from the monocular vision
of robots,here the device used is a ardrone(quad-rotor).*/
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
namespace enc = sensor_msgs::image_encodings;
static const char WINDOW[] = "Image window";
     
float prevVelocity_angular ,prevVelocity_linear ,newVelocity_angular ,newVelocity_linear ;
float derive_angular, derive_linear, dt = 0.5;
float horizontalcount;
     
class ImageConverter
{
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Publisher pub ;
  ros::Publisher tog;
  image_transport::ImageTransport it_;    
  image_transport::Subscriber image_sub_; //image subscriber 
  image_transport::Publisher image_pub_; //image publisher(we subscribe to ardrone image_raw)
  std_msgs::String msg;
public:
  ImageConverter()
    : it_(nh_)
  {
      pub= n.advertise<turtlesim::Velocity>("/drocanny/vanishing_points", 500);//
      image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("/ardrone/image_raw", 1, &ImageConverter::imageCb, this);
      image_pub_= it_.advertise("/arcv/Image",1);    
  }
     
  ~ImageConverter()
  {
    cv::destroyWindow(WINDOW);
  }
     
  void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
  {
     
     sensor_msgs::CvBridge bridge;//we need this object bridge for facilitating conversion from ros-img to opencv
   IplImage* img = bridge.imgMsgToCv(msg,"rgb8");  //image being converted from ros to opencv using cvbridge
   turtlesim::Velocity velMsg;
 CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
     CvSeq* lines = 0;
       int i,c,d;
       float c1[50]; 
       float m,angle;
          float buf;
          float m1;
       float dis;
       int k=0,k1=0; 
      int count=0;  
     
      float xv;
      float yv;
      int vc=0;
     float xvan=0,yvan=0;
      static float xvan1=0,yvan1=0;
    float num=0;
   static float count1=0;
  float dv;
float vxx,vyy;
     
         cvSetImageROI(img, cvRect(0, 0,170, 140));
        IplImage* out1 = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );   //make sure to feed the image(img) data to the parameters necessary for canny edge output 
        IplImage* gray_out = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 ); 
        IplImage* canny_out = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
        IplImage* gray_out1=cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );
          IplImage* canny_out1 = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
          IplImage* canny_out2 = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
     
        cvSmooth( img, out1, CV_GAUSSIAN, 11, 11 );
     
      cvCvtColor(out1 , gray_out, CV_RGB2GRAY);
        cvCanny( gray_out, canny_out, 50, 125, 3 );
      cvCvtColor(canny_out ,gray_out1, CV_GRAY2BGR);
     
     
     
       lines = cvHoughLines2( canny_out, storage, CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC, 1, CV_PI/180, 80,50, 10 );
        for( i = 0; i < lines->total; i++ )
        {    
     
             CvPoint* line = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(lines,i);
{           
{
cvLine( out1, line[0], line[1], CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1, 8 );
cvLine( gray_out1, line[0], line[1], CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2, 8 );
xv=line[0].x-line[1].x;
yv=line[0].y-line[1].y;
velMsg.linear = atan2(xv,yv)*180 /3.14159265;
angle=velMsg.linear;
if(velMsg.linear<-90)
{
  velMsg.linear=velMsg.linear+180;
}
buf=(line[0].x+line[1].x)/2;
     
if(abs(85-buf)<=15)
{
velMsg.angular =0;
}
else
{
velMsg.angular =(85-(line[0].x+line[1].x)/2);
}
     
if(abs(velMsg.angular)>50)
{
velMsg.angular =0;
}
     
     
     
     
     
printf("\nX::Y::X1::Y1::%d:%d:%d:%d",line[0].x,line[0].y,line[1].x,line[1].y);
     
pub.publish(velMsg);
     
     
} 
     
     
     
}
     
cvSeqRemove(lines,i);
     
{
         cvShowImage( "OUT1", out1 );//lines projected onto the real picture
        cvShowImage( "GRAY_OUT1", gray_out1 );
        cv::waitKey(3);
   sensor_msgs::ImagePtr out = sensor_msgs::CvBridge::cvToImgMsg(img, "rgb8");//image converted from opencv to ros for publishing
   image_pub_.publish(out);
 cvClearMemStorage(storage);
cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);
}
     
};
     
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_converter");
  ImageConverter ic;
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt of the package "roscv" ;

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(roscv)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  ardrone_autonomy
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  std_srvs
  turtlesim
)
find_package(OpenCV)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})




catkin_package(
    CATKIN_DEPENDS
     ardrone_autonomy
     cv_bridge
     image_transport
     roscpp
     sensor_msgs
     std_msgs
     std_srvs
     turtlesim
)


catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include
LIBRARIES roscv
CATKIN_DEPENDS ardrone_autonomy cv_bridge image_transport opencv2 roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs std_srvs turtlesim
DEPENDS system_lib
)

add_executable(linefollowing src/linefollowing.cpp)

target_link_libraries(linefollowing ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
install(TARGETS linefollowing
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

any suggestions on how to tackle this issue guys? thank you in advance

Comment: `using: command not found` did you try to **run a C++ source file as a shell script/executable**? that won't work. you need to use a compiler. and you should read the documentation of the things you use, before you use them.

Comment: As said, you're trying to run the `.cpp` file directly. Are you actually building the package? If so, what does your `CMakeLists.txt` look like?

Comment: oh ok, I have tried that as well, the issue is after "cmake ." in the package directory I get no errors and I do the "catkin_make" in the ws directory, and I find no executable file for the corresponding .cpp file in the "devel/lib/roscv" in both the workspace's devel directory and package's devel directory. I have pasted my package roscv's CMakeLists.txt below, please do let me know if there is any solution to this @Christoph Rackwitz .Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `CMakeLists.txt` you're actually compiling the file to `linefollowing` in the package `roscv`. Thus, if you're trying to use `rosrun` the command should be: `rosrun roscv linefollowing`. Notice the `.cpp` isn't included here. This is because what you were trying to run was a cpp source file. These are not directly executable and have to be compiled first.

Comment: i have tired the command "rosrun roscv linefollowing" but i throws error saying                      "[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named linefollowing below /home/badhrisrini/line_follow_ws/src/roscv" .       i have tried running the command "source devel/setup.bash" but it still says the same!! i tried searching the workspace directory of the executable file "linefollowing" but i cant find one!! please do let me know is there any solution for it!! thank you @BTables

Comment: Are you running `catkin build roscv`?

Comment: No haven't tried that i just run "catkin_make" in line_following_ws directory

Comment: Where do i need to run this "catkin build roscv" command ....inside the package directory or normaly where we do catkin_make? @BTables